# Wrap single word inline jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on an inline squirrel parse for syntax highlighting and I had been trying to use .code:contains and .wrap with a span to select an inline word.
Example:

```
<div class="code">
    function Entity::MoveTo(newx,newy,newz)
{
    x = newx;
    y = newy;
    z = newz;
}
</div>
```

With this line of jQuery:

```
$(".code:contains('function')").wrap('<span class="function"></span>');
```

This turns the whole div red, rather that just the word 'function'. 
Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are selecting an element that contains the word, you are not selecting the text. There are plenty of questions here about how to wrap a word in a span.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? :

```
var text = $(".code").text();
text  = text.replace('function','<span class="function">function</span>');
$(".code").html(text);
```